# How to share user session between websocket and http in sailsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

The story is, I have 2 potocol in my sails.js server, this sails server is only for API access, and some API are MUST logged-in to access, the websocket is also running on this server.

In the sails when I login then put the user data in req.session.me, this will save the user data in session, next time I through http to access then I can get save data from req.session.me.
Reference: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/sessions

The question is saving data in user session req.session.me through http to access the server then cannot get back req.session.me through websocket to access the server.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution?